# JQuery Validation remote JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-validate

I have a problem with jquery validation remote and my form submit.
Look this code http://jsfiddle.net/35cHS/135/

```
<form id="fail">
    <label>Documento:</label>
    <input id="numero_documento" maxlength="2" name="numero_documento" maxlength="16" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Próximo" />
</form>

$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#fail').validate({
        rules: {
            numero_documento: {
                required: true
                ,remote: {
                    url: 'http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/04676090.json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        //console.log('Ok! Continue submit...');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When I insert a value and click on button it is ok. A submit is called. 
But if I uncomment the remote and again insert a value and click ok nothing happens.

I want continue with my form submit because I just want to make a search and return yes or no later.

Is it possible ?

sorry for my english I am working on it  =)

Answer (score 0):

`remote` is a bit misleading because it really just means `another file on your server` so in this particular case, you can't do a cross domain request to retreive that json object unless you're using json with padding. At this moment, CORS is restricting you. Instead, create a php file on your server, such as, `get_json.php`, and then use

```
echo file_get_contents('http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/04676090.json');
```

The server will not be limited by CORS unless the configuration on cep.correiocontrol.com.br is configured in such a way to deny these requests completely.

Comment: Hi Ohgodwhy... I already tried it. For security reasons I have changed this URL, my real URL is called verifica_documento2.php and return echo json_encode($value)... but the same problem occured Tks